# Apache Atlas - how to install on EMR and how to change user/password

Tags: linux, apache, hadoop, amazon-ec2

I am looking to install Apache Atlas and test APIs on AWS EMR.

Reading trough `https://atlas.apache.org/InstallationSteps.html` but do not see how to change user/pass.

What is default user/pass and how to change and is above installation the best way for EMR on AWS?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is available to me.
https://community.hortonworks.com/questions/144519/how-to-change-default-atlas-ui-admin-password.html

if you want to change user/password from admin/admin to admin/Password

**Step 1: Generate the sha256 password string**

```
# echo -n "Password" | sha256sum  
e7cf3ef4f17c3999a94f2c6f612e8a888e5b1026878e4e19398b23bd38ec221a
```

**Step 2: Modify the conf/users-credentials.properties file**

```
#username=group::sha256-password
admin=ADMIN::8c6976e5b5410415bde908bd4dee15dfb167a9c873fc4bb8a81f6f2ab448a918
rangertagsync=RANGER_TAG_SYNC::e3f67240f5117d1753c940dae9eea772d36ed5fe9bd9c94a300e40413f1afb9d
```

-->

```
#username=group::sha256-password
admin=ADMIN::e7cf3ef4f17c3999a94f2c6f612e8a888e5b1026878e4e19398b23bd38ec221a # (replace the string)
rangertagsync=RANGER_TAG_SYNC::e3f67240f5117d1753c940dae9eea772d36ed5fe9bd9c94a300e40413f1afb9d
```

**Step 3: restart the Atlas service.**